# ASP.MVC: Post model to other controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view-model that looks like this:

```
public class HomeIndexViewModel
{

    public List<Project> FeaturedProjects { get; set; }

    public RegisterViewModel RegisterViewModel { get; set; }

}
```

I'm trying to Post to this action in AccountController:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("konto/registrera")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
   ...
}
```

On Home view I write `@Html.EditorFor(e => e.RegisterViewModel))` to get this partial:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-inline" , role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();

    ...
}
```

Looking at HTML id names produced it seems that this post and entire HomeIndexViewModel to Register. How do I modify this to only post a RegisterViewModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using:

```
@Html.Partial("_Register", new RegisterViewModel())
```

in Home view.